# Bootstrap3, modal with transparent overlay, but also close it with click outside of the modal

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#myBtn2").click(function() {
        $("#myModal2").modal({
          backdrop: false
        });
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <h2>Modal</h2>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" id="myBtn2">Modal</button>
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal2" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">

        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Modal</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I found that `{backdrop: false}` can make modal's overlay be transparent.

But It prevent closing modal from click outside of the modal.

**Question:** 
How can I make it enabled to `close modal` through `click outside of the modal` , At the same time, The modal's overlay remained transparent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `opacity:0` to the backdrop element, and remove `backdrop:false`

```css
.modal-backdrop {
  opacity:0!important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#myBtn2").click(function() {
        $("#myModal2").modal();
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <h2>Modal</h2>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" id="myBtn2">Modal</button>
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal2" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">

        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Modal</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the following style

```
.modal-backdrop.in {
    filter: alpha(opacity=0); // For IE
    opacity: 0; // For all other browsers
}
```

Also there is no need of backdrop: false now.

But one thing that i want to mention is that although you will be able to see whats in the background, it wont be clickable or accessible until the modal closes.

Comment: Thanks for your nice answer. Sorry for not choosing your answer.

Comment: Its ok, but the ans you selected, will give you issues in lower versions of IE. Rest your question,your wish :)